# How to create a svn repository for Local Network?

Tags: php, svn, repository, lan

I want to create a SVN repository in Local Network. So other systems in the network can access the SVN repository. I want to develop this for PHP developers is my company. Is there any opensource PHP application available to establish SVN repository? How to create SVN repository for local network ?

Comment: Almost all version control tools allow so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can establish a `svn` server as well locally.

Another approach woud be a distributed VCS like Mercurial, git or bazaar.

Comment: I think a distributed VCS for a project which is only going to accessed locally would be an overkill. From the description I think even CVS may suit his needs(although I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Can we use this feature without internet connection(in offline) ?

Comment: @Ravi maybe - but I have switched to `hg` on all my projects, nearly all of them I work alone with. It is not much more complex in use than a non-D VCS and has much more flexibility.

Comment: @Balaji53444 Of course - you can establish the (`svn`) server locally - or, if you use `hg`, you can even exchange changesets with a USB stick or something.

Comment: @glglgl heh I am planning to do the exact thing i.e. SVN -> mercurial, I was comparing git with mercurial and I think I am gonna go with mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/percept/svn_starters_guide.pdf

If you would like to try CVS you can find some info here: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~srevilak/cvs.html

PS: I suggest you google before asking.